# only count distinct values in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table which holds user messages:

```
id | msg_id | recipient | sender
1       1         4         8
2       1         4         8
3       1         4         8
4       6         4         8
```

i am trying to count the rows of msg_id, however i want to use a distinct function which will only count each number once. so if number '1' appears 4 times, the count should only count '1' once and ignore the other rows.

can someone please show me how i can achieve this.

so far i have this which counts all the rows of msg_id, how can i change it to count distinct, thanks.

```
function check_new_messages() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND deleted_to='0' AND read_message='0' AND from_user_id != '0'";
            $check_new_messages_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_new_messages_set);
            return $check_new_messages_set;     
        }
```

Output:

```
<?php
$check_new_messages_set = check_new_messages();
while ($new = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_messages_set)) { 
echo "". $new['COUNT(id)'] .""; 
?><? } ?>
```

Comment: You want to count all the distinct rows?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id) ...`?

Comment: yes but still counts all of the 1's in the row

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT msg_id)  FROM ptb_messages GROUP BY msg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM ptb_messages GROUP BY msg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL statement to:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT msg_id) FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id=`